# Changing the data structure used by an AngularJS $resource's $save function

Tags: angularjs

We have several models in our web application that have different view / create models.

For instance, suppose a theoretical application where you can add users to groups. When displaying the group, it is useful to include the users. That is, a GET to /api/groups should return something like this:

```
[
    {
        id: "groups/1",
        name: "Administrators",
        users: [
            {id: "users/1", name: "Ted"},
            {id: "users/2", name: "Bill"},
            {id: "users/3", name: "Robert"}
        ]
    }
]
```

However, when creating a group, it seems silly to post the entire user. In this example, the users are small, but in practice, they can contain many properties (images, addresses, what have you). The server will need to load the users and do something with them upon group creation anyway, so there's no need to post all of that stuff back. I'd like the post to look like this:

```
[
    {
        id: "groups/2",
        name: "Wheel",
        users: [ "users/8", "users/9", "users/10" ]
    }
]
```

When defining my resource, I have something like this:

```
angular.module('resources').factory('Group', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/groups', {}, {
            save: {
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/api/groups',
                transformRequest: function(requestData, headersGetter) {
                    //manipulate the request here
                    //Herein lies my problem
                    //requestData.users = requestData.users.map(function(u) {return u.id;})
                }
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Unfortunately, `requestData` isn't the group instance, but rather something that can be passed to `group.$save()`. When `$save()` is called with no arguments, `requestData` is undefined. How are you supposed to accomplish this? I'd *really* rather not just fall back on using $http.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put your controller code that will be helpful. But If you inject Group factory into your controller, you need to have something like this:

```
var group = new Group();
group.push(newUserObject); 
group.$save();
```

But it will be much better when you post your controller code.

Comment: There's not much to the controller code. Basically, it's `$scope.group = new Group()` at the start, inputs are bound to the values, and then in the save handler there's `$scope.group.$save()`.